# generating unique random id using javascript and redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I want to generate a random id for each user and save it in a redis set using node.js. My first approach was to generate a random id and then check it's uniqueness using redis SISMEMBER and if it wasn't unique repeat the task above using a loop. The problem is that node redis is asynchronous, So, I can't implement the loop described above. I also thought about using promises like below:

```js
var promises = [], f=1;
while(f){
    suggested_id = new_random_id();
    promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        red_client.sismember("uids", suggested_id, function(err, value) {
            if(err) {reject(err); }
            resolve(value);
        });
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'foo');
    }));
    Promise.all(promises).then((values)=>{
        f = values[0];
    });
}
}
```

but again Promises.all is another asynchronous function so the loop starts making 
innumerable calls to redis without waiting for response from the previous one. Does anyone have an idea how can this be done?

Comment: I would suggest using a UID generator.  eg. https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: Unfortunately, the id needs to be at most 10 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you just waiting for the promise to finish with success and then run your job

```
const getUniqueId = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  const generateId = async () => {
    suggested_id = new_random_id();
    red_client.sismember("uids", suggested_id, function(err, value) {
        if(err) {
          // call generateId again, this is the retry
          generateId () 
          return
        }
        resolve(suggested_id);
    });
   })

   generateId()
})


const uniqueId = await getUniqueId()
```

Note: considering the fact that you check for the id and later one you'll use it you risk loosing the id in the mean time.

Comment: The problem is that you can only use await in async functions, and unfortunately my main function isn't one (the id should be sent back to user in response to her request)

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Strip wait away and use getUniqueId().then(res => {}). I don't know if your response to the request needs to be sync or async. If it needs to be sync you're out of luck and your only change is to generate a random id.